# NSThread Retain Count

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, object, nsthread

Why is the Retain count of my thread = 2??
It gets incremented after the start method why ?
How does Retain count work for NSThreads

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSThread *thread;

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(check) object:nil];
                    NSLog(@"RC == %lu",(unsigned long)[thread retainCount]);
        [thread start];
    }

    NSLog(@"RC == %lu",(unsigned long)[thread retainCount]);
}// presently stopped here on breakpoint

-(void)check{
       for (int i = 0 ; i< 100000; i++) {
           NSLog(@"NEW THREAD ==%d",i);
       }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it works, as you discovered: `start` will retain your NSThread so it does live through its execution. [`+[NSThread exit]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/exit) will decrement that retain count once you are done with it.

On another hand, think about this: you are creating an `NSThread` and assigning its (retained) reference to a local variable. How are you going to decrement it? The local variable will not be visible outside of `viewDidLoad`, so you cannot release it.

A correct way of handling this is using an ivar for your your `NSThread` instance, so you can release it in `dealloc`, or use an `autorelease`d `NSThread`, counting on the fact that `start` will retain that object. So you can have:

```
        - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];

            NSThread *thread;

            @autoreleasepool
            {
                thread = [[[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(check) object:nil] autorelease];
                    NSLog(@"RC == %lu",(unsigned long)[thread retainCount]);
                [thread start];
            }
```

and everything will be correct.

I hope this explains why `start` retains the thread.

Comment: could you please explain me if I am using '    NSLog(@"RC == %lu",(unsigned long)[thread retainCount]);
' after the @autorlease {} the it's giving retainCount 3 on Xcode 6.1.

Comment: @Sandy: you cannot rely on retainCount to provide that kind of low-level information in a way that makes sense to you, this is clearly stated in Apple docs. You could just make guesses about what happens inside of Apple frameworks.